# HY000/1045 versus 28000/1045 issues

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, server-side

Without being rude, yes I know that both are a authentification problem as I have been searching for a solution on SO for over a week now.

However...
Here is some more insight of my particular problem. I have 2 Godaddy accounts, one of my own, and one for my client. On my own account everything works great without any authentification issue towards my Database. My clients account has the exact same products as mine (apart that he has a .com domain, where I have a .eu domain. In case this could be the cause) and he has no ssl certificate, which I believe is now problem as my the connection to my own database also worked before I had an ssl.

On both hosting accounts I have uploaded a script called masterConnection.php which takes care of connecting to the databases on both accounts. The database on my client's account was created the same way it was created on my own account, and I have created a user with all privilages and connected it to the database, again, the exact same way as I did on my own account.

When trying to connect to my clients database, it results in the HY000/1045 error which I know is a authentification error. So I first started with retyping each and every value, even copy/pasting it to eliminate all typo's, and even created new users with the most simplest username and password, but without succes...

```
<?php
$db_name = "weshopoutlet";
$mysql_username = "WeShopper";
$mysql_password = "Password";
$server_name = "weshopoutlet.com";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);       
?>
```

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'WeShopper'@'ip-160-153-129-238.ip.secureserver.net' (using password:
>   YES) in /home/weshopoutlet/public_html/appData/masterConnection.php on
>   line 6

The IP adress of this server is indeed 160.153.129.238

But here is the thing...
When I on purpose fill in a wrong password in my own script on my own server, I get a 28000/1045 error instead like this:

```
<?php
$db_name = "GOODDBname";
$mysql_username = "GOODUsername";
$mysql_password = "WRONGPassword";
$server_name = "indiehostservice.eu";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);       
?>
```

(keep in mind that this one works if I have the correct password filled in!)

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'GOODUsername'@'ip-160-153-162-137.ip.secureserver.net' (using password:
>   YES) in /home/indiehostservice/public_html/subFolder/masterConnection.php on
>   line 6

Again, the IP is correct, however the actuall subFolder is left out in this case.

At this point I am starting to doubt if the HY000/1045 actually is a authentification problem, as the posts I saw with the HY000/1045 errors have never been solved (as far as I have seen them). So in order to see if this wasnt an issue with the Godaddy server, I have called them to see what we can do and we have tried the following:

- Resetting the PHP version
- Using different PHP versions
- Resetting the entire server about 3 times
- Different domain settings
- Different security settings

All without succes. So again I turn to you guys. What else can I try to find the source of this issue, or even better, how do I solve this? It seems more people are experiencing HY000/1045 issues that havent been solved so far.

Thanks!

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'WeShopper'@'ip-160-153-129-238.ip.secureserver.net'`  -- note that the hostname here is not the IP address, so you have to make sure that you set up permissions for the correct host. Or `select user,host from mysql.user;` to check for user/host combinations there.

Comment: it is the show grants for the `%` host

Comment: he / she would not have done `Grant` on a jillion email address

Comment: `%` host is to allow from all hosts, but I'm really hoping that the OP didn't create a user `'WeShopper'@'%' `. Talk about a security hole!

Comment: I can guarantee you that the IP is not whitelisted and that `%` is the only strategy

Comment: @aynber I am not allowed to do that command for some reason, it keeps telling my i not authorized. Also, where are you guys seeing that %? All I created was that test user with all permissions, but it isnt even allowed in.

All I wanna know is why does this result in a different error on my system, and not on my client's system?